# Pytorch-Change Minibatch Size while training

Tags: python, pytorch

How do you change the minibatch size while training? I do not want to re-initialize the dataloader because I want to keep track of the index.

Comment: can you elaborate your need? or do you want to change the batch size anytime? I guess that is not possible with dataloader.

Comment: If you have a specific need, you may write your own batch-sampler. However, if you want to modify batch size anytime during training, then I think that is not doable.